# Close all files opened in python module when the module is stopped abnormally

Tags: python

In my module, one block is coded like this:

```
# open a text file to which results obtained in MAINBLOCK will be written
write2file = open('myResults.txt','w')
#    MAINBLOCK
write2file.close()
```

When running the module, I may interrupt the module in `IDLE` by `Ctrl+C` for program debugging or exceptions may be raised in `MAINBLOCK`, so the module is stopped abnormally. However, If I try to delete `myResults.txt` in Windows Explorer at the time, the message says:

```
The action can't be completed because the file is open in pythonw.exe
```

I think if the module is stopped abnormally, the file is still opening, am I right? How can I close all those open file identifiers in `IDLE` or by other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to ensure all files are closed even if an exception occurs:

```
with open("myResults.txt", "w") as write2file:
    # do stuff
```

No need to close the file - it will be closed automatically as soon as your program exits from the `with` block.

Comment: Thanks. I know `with` is a better choice. But sometimes I will use `write2file = open('myResults.txt','w')` directly to avoid too many indentation levels. So I'm still interested in how to figure the open file problem if the program can't reach `write2file.close()`. Is there a module in python to close all open file in `IDLE`

Comment: You won't get around extra indentation if you want to introduce more control. The alternative would be wrapping the code that uses the opened file in a `try` block and put an `except` clause there to close the file and then re-`raise` the exception. But that's a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, I believe a file can always be closed from the prompt in the Python shell window:-

> > > file_name.close()

That's worked for me whenever a program has aborted execution due to an exception. But it would be very useful if there was a 'catch-all' close method that closed all open files.